# priority queue and structs

Tags: c++, struct, priority-queue

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
struct Call
{
    Call( int callNum, long callTime, int callLength ) :
    CallNum( callNum ), CallTime( callTime ), CallLength( callLength ) { }
    int CallNum;
    long CallTime;
    int CallLength;
};

bool operator>( const Call& lhs, const Call& rhs ) {
    return lhs.CallLength > rhs.CallLength;
}

ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, const Call& c ) {
    os << c.CallNum << " " << c.CallTime << " " << c.CallLength;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    priority_queue< Call, vector<Call>, greater<Call> > q; 
    q.push( Call( 1, 200, 150 ));
    q.push( Call( 2, 300, 950 ));
    q.push( Call( 3, 100, 450 ));
    q.push( Call( 4, 150, 320 ));
    unsigned i=0, n=q.size();
    for ( i=0; i<n; ++i ) {
        cout << q.top() << endl;
        q.pop();
    }
}
```

This is my code. My problem is, When I use `q.top();` it prints to screen `callNum, callTime, callLength`. But I want to use them seperately.

I mean How can I print to screen just callTime? for ex: `q.top(callTime);` or something else? who can help me?

Comment: Have you written this code yourself? Because if you have, I can't believe that you are asking this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you just looking for:

```
cout << q.top().CallNum << endl;
```

and so on?